# Toggle classes onlick from multiple instances

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick, toggle

So I ran into a problem regarding my toggle function. In my current case I would like to be able to turn parts of the web-based interface on and off (display:none and block). I got it to work from one of the windows but the snag I hit was when I added multiple calls to the same functions. I reverted from using getElementById and used getElementsByClass instead. This caused no problems as far as I know of. When I added the second menu however things started to malfunction.

I'll paste my code and a jsFiddle down below.

My goal is to make the onclick on the `<li>` toggle the other `<li>` and toggle the map/cesium at the same time.

HTML

```
<div id="map">
    <nav id="primary_nav_wrap">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">=</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a class="buttonMap" href="#" onclick="toggleMap('none')">Toggle Map</a></li>
              <li><a class="buttonMap2" href="#" onclick="toggleMap('block')">Toggle Map</a></li>
              <li><a class="buttonCesium" href="#" onclick="toggleCesium('none')">Toggle Cesium</a></li>
              <li><a class="buttonCesium2" href="#" onclick="toggleCesium('none')">Toggle Cesium</a></li>
             </ul>
           </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
<div id="cesium">
    <nav id="primary_nav_wrap">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">=</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a class="buttonMap" href="#" onclick="toggleMap('none')">Toggle Map</a></li>
              <li><a class="buttonMap2" href="#" onclick="toggleMap('block')">Toggle Map</a></li>
              <li><a class="buttonCesium" href="#" onclick="toggleCesium('none')">Toggle Cesium</a></li>
              <li><a class="buttonCesium2" href="#" onclick="toggleCesium('block')">Toggle Cesium</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

CSS (minimal but so JsFiddle gets the point across)

```
#map{
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  background-color:red;
}
#cesium{
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  background-color:blue;
}
```

JS

```
function toggleMap(display) {
            var elem = document.getElementById("map");
            var buttonMap = document.getElementsByClassName("buttonMap");
            elem.style.display = display;
            buttonMap.style.display = display;
            if (buttonMap.style.display === 'none'){
                buttonMap2.style.display = 'block';
            }
            else if (buttonMap.style.display === 'block'){
                buttonMap2.style.display = 'none';
            }
};

function toggleCesium(display) {
            var elem = document.getElementById("cesium");
            var buttonCesium = document.getElementsByClassName("buttonCesium");
            elem.style.display = display;
            buttonCesium.style.display = display;
            if (buttonCesium.style.display === 'none'){
                buttonCesium2.style.display = 'block';
            }
            else if (buttonCesium.style.display === 'block'){
                buttonCesium2.style.display = 'none';
            }
};
```

In the [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rz4wu4qd/14/), the colored  blocks should disappear.

Any help is appreciated!

(PS! We can safely assume users will be using up-to-date browsers)

Comment: `buttonCesium2` is not defined and will throw an error if you try to use it, hence stopping the execution of the script. Same for `buttonMap2`.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand what you're trying to do. Is it normal that your first block of `<li>` has `id` and your other block has `class`?

Comment: @Pierre-LoupPagniez That was a mistake on my part, i noticed it right after i posted the question. I'll update my HTML. Thanks for taking a look at my code anyway!

Comment: Would this do what you want? https://jsfiddle.net/rz4wu4qd/17/ I believe that the way jsFiddle is made doesn't allow getElementsByClassName to function properly in your case, because of iframes, so you will have to test it on your side directly.

Comment: That does it for my toggle function! I'll figure the buttons disapearing out on my own. If you make your jsFiddle into an anwer ill mark it as accepted for you. Thanks again mate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/rz4wu4qd/18/
Somewhat working solution as mentioned in comments.
`getElementsByClassName` returns an array, so you need to iterate through it, for example with a `for` loop.